# Entity Framework Code first DbConfiguration for Multiple database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework

I am using EF6 with Multiple Databases(SQL SERVER,ORACLE) 
We are Migrating from SQL Server to Oracle. everything works in SQL server. In Oracle we are facing issue of trim char column. i have used this link [trailing-blanks-issue-in-string-joins](https://romiller.com/2014/10/20/ef6-1workaround-trailing-blanks-issue-in-string-joins/) to solve issue. but by default this intercept is applying for SQL Server. i want to apply this to Oracle. 
what i have done is

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
        {
            public MyConfiguration()
            {
                SetProviderServices("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", EFOracleProviderServices.Instance);
                SetProviderFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", OracleClientFactory.Instance);
                AddInterceptor(new StringTrimmerInterceptor());

            }
        }
```

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(EBS.DAL.Model.MyConfiguration))] 
        public class EBS_GIROdbContext : DbContext
        {

            static EBS_GIROdbContext()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<EBS_GIROdbContext>(null);

            }
            //NeoSampleGIRODBEntities
            //OracleDbContext
            public EBS_GIROdbContext()
                : base("Name=OracleDbContext")
            {

            }
```

in GLOBAL.ASAX

```
  DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new EBS.DAL.Model.MyConfiguration());
```

still it is applying for SQL SERVER. How can i add DbConfiguration for Oracle.
i am not able to get it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

```
public sealed class EntityFrameworkConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public static readonly DbConfiguration Instance = new EntityFrameworkConfiguration();

        EntityFrameworkConfiguration()
        {
            this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new OracleConnectionFactory());
            this.SetProviderServices("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", EFOracleProviderServices.Instance);
             this.AddInterceptor(new StringTrimmerInterceptor());

        }
    }
```

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(EntityFrameworkConfiguration))] 
    public class EBS_GIROdbContext : DbContext
    {

        static EBS_GIROdbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<EBS_GIROdbContext>(null);
        }
```

in Global.ASAX

```
 DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(EntityFrameworkConfiguration.Instance);
```

this setting will add trim function in All select query for varchar2 data type like this

```
SELECT
    "Extent1"."LBRCODE" AS "LBRCODE",
    LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."CAT")) AS "CAT",
    LTRIM(RTRIM("Extent1"."CATTYPE")) AS "CATTYPE",
```